# ASP Login Not Working

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, forms, authentication

So previously my login worked fine. And then I made some edits and it stopped working. Here are the edits I made to my website in between it going from working to not working.

1. I was trying to make a submit content page but I kept getting errors about not being able to contain a form inside a form. So I went over to my master page and removed the form tag and then added all the form tags I needed into each individual page. In the end I ended up removing all form tags and putting a single form tag around the content place holder in the master page.
2. I added a new table to my SQL database to store content submitted by users. I use Microsoft Server Express for my database.

The error I am getting is not an error in my console, it is just that my `PostBackURL` is loaded with out anything happen. Even if I enter a correct login (I have checked and the login info I tested is stored in my database), it will just automatically load the `PostBackURL` with no login occuring, nor any Login failed messages.

**Web Config:**

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
            </forms>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

**Master Page (Relevant Parts):**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="header headerLogin">
            <img style="margin-left: 5vw; margin-top: 5px; height: 32px; width: 130px;" src="images/inshortlogo.png" />
            <p class="taskbarLinks">
                <a href="home.aspx" style="margin-right: 1em;">HOME</a>
                <a href="news.aspx" style="margin-right: 1em;">NEWS</a>
                <a href="#" style="margin-right: 1em;">JOB LISTINGS</a>
                <a href="#" style="margin-right: 1em;">STUDY</a>
                <a href="login.aspx" style="margin-right: 3em;" runat="server" id="loginButton">LOGIN</a>
            </p>
            <script>
                ...
            </script>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
    Login Page:

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <div class="Absolute-Center">
            <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" colspan="2">Log In</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl08$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl08$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" CssClass="button" PostBackUrl="~/home.aspx" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="ctl08$Login1" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                    </asp:Login>
                    <br />
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <a class="button" style="margin-right: 2em;" href="signup.aspx">Register</a>
                        <a class="button" href="forgotpassword.aspx">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="logOutLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="logOutButton" runat="server" class="button" OnClick="logOutButton_Click">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        <style>
            .Absolute-Center {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            }
        </style>
    </asp:Content>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the postbackurl. That posts the form to another page, so of course you don't get logged in. Instead, upon successful login, perform a redirect to whatever page you want.